# How to implement queue conflation

Tags: c#, queue

Suppose I have a BlockingCollection queue and I am adding the following events:

A -> B1 -> C -> B2 -> B1

I basically only care about the last B1 event. I want to be able to discard the other B1's in front of it in this scenario (but still process B2 since it is using a different ID value than B1). It seems like with a BlockingCollection I cannot achieve this unless I can control when B1 or B2 gets added each time which I do not know when another B will be added.

I thought about creating a separate data structure containing the B events (it would be a ConcurrentDictionary where the key type is an ID value - if 2 B events with the same ID value are added one after the other, than the first one would effectively be discarded because it would be overwritten in the dictionary). The problem with this is that I lose the ordering of all events which is important. I still want events to be processed in the order shown above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need first in first out?

Comment: Yes I need first in first out.

Comment: If you only want the last B1 event to be executed, are you willing to risk B1 events never being processed?  How do you want to handle the possibility that B1 events will be constantly pushed back?

Comment: Basically, if the queue already contains a B event by the time I add another B event, I want it to overwrite that first B event. Otherwise, the queue should process events as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ConflatingQueue<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private readonly Queue<TKey> keys = new Queue<TKey>();

    public void Enqueue(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(key, value);
            keys.Enqueue(key);
        }
    }

    public TValue Dequeue()
    {
        var key = keys.Dequeue();
        var value = dict[key];
        dict.Remove(key);
        return value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            yield return dict[key];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //A -> B1 -> C -> B2 -> B1
        var cq = new ConflatingQueue<string, string>();
        cq.Enqueue("A", "A");
        cq.Enqueue("B1", "B1");
        cq.Enqueue("C", "C");
        cq.Enqueue("B2", "B2");
        cq.Enqueue("B1", "B1");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", cq)); //A,B1,C,B2
    }
```

I'll leave making it multi-threaded as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It has been a long time since I faced this issue and ended up solving it myself in a different way than the above answer. But I really like your solution and would have been better. I don't work for that company anymore though. ;) Accepting this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just to note that this solution is not thread safe. 
You can use a a Concurrent dictionary and queue

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, here are a few options:

- Implement counters or flags such that only a single instance of a B event type can exist on the queue.
- Set up a "B event" dictionary such that your key is the id of the B event and the value is the reference to the corresponding queue node.  If a new B event enters the queue, do a lookup in the dictionary.  If one already exists of that type, just swap out the queue node for a new one with the new B event or simply point the node's reference to the new B event instance.  Since you're only changing the queue node belonging to the old B event instance, you won't lose the ordering of other items.